# Make creates empty dependency when using rules generated from gcc -MM

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a makefile that compiles all the cpp files in the src directory whenever they change, or whenever a header that they include changes. My problem is that when a file includes enough files to where gcc wraps the rule to a new line, [as per the documentation for using the -M options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), make treats the line break as another space and the rule tries to create an empty dependency.

For example, running the makefile with a file in the src directory called `source.cpp` containing:

```
#include "header1.hpp"
#include "header2.hpp"
#include "header3.hpp"
#include "header4.hpp"
#include "header5.hpp"
```

will output something along the lines of:

```
Missing file header1.hpp
Missing file header2.hpp
Missing file header3.hpp
Missing file
Missing file header4.hpp
Missing file header5.hpp
Compiling src/source.cpp...
```

This is my makefile right now:

```
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj

SRCFLS = $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name *.cpp)
OBJFLS = $(call getobj,$(SRCFLS))

CXXFLAGS = -c -I .

define \n


endef

define \t

endef

define getobj
$(subst $(SRCDIR)/,$(OBJDIR)/,$(subst .cpp,.o,$(1)))
endef

define getrule
$(shell $(CXX) -MM -MG -MT $(call getobj,$(1)) $(1))
endef

default : $(OBJFLS);

% :
    @echo Missing file $@

$(eval $(foreach FLE,$(SRCFLS),\
\
$(call getrule,$(FLE))$(\n)$(\t)\
    @echo Compiling $$<...$(\n)$(\t)\
    @mkdir $$(@D) -p$(\n)$(\t)\
    @-$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $$< -o $$@$(\n)\
\
))
```

Sorry if the question is confusing, I'm willing to clear up any details needed.

Comment: This seems pretty complicated to me.  Why not do something simpler, such as http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: I thought it was over complicated, I'll read through the page you linked, thanks.